# is there any other method to solve this problem?

Tags: python, python-3.x, collections, counter, python-itertools

Input File:

```
geeks:G
for:F
geeks:G
geeks:G
geek:H
for:F
geek:H
```

Output:

```
The count of geeks:g is 3
The count of for:f is 2
The count of geek:h is 2
```

```
from collections import Counter
       with open("H:\doc.txt","r") as file:
            for line in file:
                w=list(line.split())
                new=[]
                for i in w:
                   new.append(i)
                   print(Counter(new))
```

it is not showing the output as per my need

Comment: What's wrong with it?

Comment: Please update the indentation of your code. Python is very sensitive to indentation, as are python programmers.

Answer (score 2):

This is all you need:

```
>>> c = Counter(line.strip().lower() for line in open("H:\doc.txt","r"))
Counter({'geeks:G': 3, 'geek:H': 2, 'for:F': 2})
>>> for i, val in c.items():
...     print("The count of {} is {}".format(i, val))
... 
The count of geek:H is 2
The count of for:F is 2
The count of geeks:G is 3
```

If you want it ordered, you can sort it before iterating.

```
>>> for i, val in sorted(c.items(), key = lambda x: - x[1]):
...     print("The count of {} is {}".format(i, val))

The count of geeks:G is 3
The count of geek:H is 2
The count of for:F is 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {"names":[
'geeks:G',
'for:F',
'geeks:G',
'geeks:G',
'geek:H',
'for:F',
'geek:H']}


df = pd.DataFrame(d)

result = df.value_counts()

print(result)
```

```
names  
geeks:G    3
for:F      2
geek:H     2
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("doc.txt","r") as file:
            dict = {}
            for line in file.readlines():
                line = line.strip()
                if line not in dict:
                    dict[line] = 1
                else:
                    dict[line] += 1
            for k, v in dict.items():
                print(f"The count of {k} is {v}")
```

Answer (score 0):

you just filed on indents, correct versions:

```
from collections import Counter

with open("H:\doc.txt","r") as file:
    for line in file:
        w=list(line.split())
        new=[]
        for i in w:
           new.append(i)
           print(Counter(new))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to initialise a `Counter` with the lower case version of all the lines:

```py
from collections import Counter

with open("H:\doc.txt","r") as file:
    for item in Counter(line.strip().lower() for line in file).items():
        print(f'The count of {item[0]} is {item[1]}')
```

Output as requested

Answer (score 0):

Only move the `new=[]` line before `with`, and move `print(Counter(new))` out of the `with` block in your code.

```
from collections import Counter

new=[]
with open("H:\doc.txt","r") as file:
    for line in file:
        w=list(line.split())
        for i in w:
            new.append(i)
print(Counter(new))
```

And then format the output content what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code just using Counter functions:

```py
from collections import Counter

with open("H:\doc.txt","r") as f:
    f.read().splitlines()

counter = Counter(f)
for k in counter.keys():
    print(f"The count of {k} is {counter[k]}")
```